# Designing auto-generated html form from MySql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm building a simple internal website for a medium-sized independent restaurant chain.  The website will be a repository for contact information, general documents, etc.  We have a central kitchen that produces and delivers around 50 different items daily to the 7 different restaurants in our city.  We currently have a pen, paper, and phone tag system for placing these orders.  The part of the site I am struggling with is creating a section for ordering these items through the internal site.

The website can be logged into currently from each restaurant's unique user id, and there is a mysql table for each restaurant's daily order.  I need to create an html form that allows the manager of each restaurant to enter integers for each item and have that information update as a new record in the mysql table.  I know it should be a straightforward task, and one that an advanced php programmers would scoff at...but that I am  not!

Any help at all would be appreciated, even a reference to an open-source solution that is well documented that would help me in getting started!

Comment: Take a look into the [ATK Framework](http://www.atk-framework.com/).

Answer (score 1):

These classes can also help you :

- [Form auto generator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/162-PHP-This-class-builds-completely-an-HTML-Form-based-in-a-description-of-the-fields-it-s-ideal-to-avoid-writing-one-form-any-new-table-you-have-to-feed-.html) ( A Simple class for creating HTML forms )
- [Forms generation and validation](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1-PHP-HTML-forms-generation-and-validation-.html) ( A professional class using for Form generation and validation )

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a Framework as @hakre suggested in this comment.  From a business perspective using a Framework is a time and money saver because you're not having to create the wheel when something in the Framework already exists:

- [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)
- [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)

and a dozen others would accomplish what you want but would take some time learning them right out of the box.

These, and many other frameworks, have form generators (command-line utilities or open sourced available Code Gallery classes), that make the forms from your database schema.

But this would only be the **LONG term solution** as this would eventually allow you to customize your site to exactly want you want but would require resources from an experienced developer to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may also want to look at phpmaker, they have a trial.  But essentially you point it at the database > enter the connection information. and it will generate add/remove/edit/delete

I just used it to build a couple sites to administer my databases on the backend.  Since I didn't need it to be all pretty and colorful for the end-user experience, it was very useful, and customizable for straight data management.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMaker is really powerfull choice. I have used it for many applications.

If you are a PHP programmer, you can go deep and do most every customization you want.

You can also install some advance extensions like [ilovephpmaker](http://www.ilovephpmaker.com/).